# C preprocessor macro that turns string into token?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, llvm, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write a C preprocessor Macro for LLVM that's used like:

```
vc(@"Browser")
```

and expands to:

```
[[BrowserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BrowserViewController" bundle:nil]
```

The best I can come up with is:

```
vc(Browser)
```

which is implemented as:

```
#define vc(xibName) [[xibName ## ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ViewController", @#xibName] bundle:nil]
```

however to the user this could seem confusing as `Browser` on its own (outside of string literals) looks like a token. `@"Browser"` would make the intent a little clearer without requiring the user to read the macro.

**EDIT:**

The motivation behind this seems silly at first glance, but I work on apps for iPhone, iPad and OS X and each has it's own way of instantiating a view controller with a view that is laid out in Interface Builder.

iPad:

```
[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardPad" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Browser"];
```

iPhone:

```
[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Browser"];
```

OS X:

```
[[BrowserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BrowserViewController" bundle:nil]
```

Since it's all Objective-C, some of my controllers are reused across platforms, and I don't like to litter my code with conditional compilation statements every time I want a view controller. Plus when working on different platforms on different days of the week it helps to know you can just call `vc(@"Browser")` and you'll get what you expect whether it's on and iPad, iPhone or MAC. It's just a question of convention vs configuration.

Comment: If you *need* this, then I suspect you should rethink your code.

Comment: To avoid confusion write a one line method with a good name.  Method call overhead is essentially negligible and clarity is much higher.

Comment: @Zaph agreed - `UIViewController` already deals with the use case when using a naming convention - I discovered this by accident when I started, but it's documented so I'm surprised people feel they need to hack their own solutions

Comment: Why not just make a function, instead of battling with macros?

Comment: OK I know it seemed a little like a silly question, see my edit above for some more info as to the "why". BTW Be careful with `UIViewController`'s naming convention, it works on iOS but not on OS X; `[BrowserViewController new]` loads the xib if it's a `UIViewController` on iOS but not so for `NSViewController` on OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a function is the way to implement this:

```
id InstantiateViewControllerWithXib(NSString *xibName) {
    NSString *className = [xibName stringByAppendingString:@"ViewController"];
    return [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] initWithNibName:className bundle:nil];
}
```

To strictly answer the question, you could then define the desired macro:

```
#define vc(xibName) InstantiateViewControllerWithXib(xibName)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just call

```
[[BrowserViewController alloc] init];
```

then [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW13) will search for a `xib` with an appropriate name in the following way

> 1. If the view controller class name ends with the word “Controller”, as in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the class name without the word “Controller”, as in MyView.nib.
> 2. It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController, it looks for a MyViewController.nib file.

The above one line of code should be short enough to not justify a macro ;)

Comment: May be even shorter? `[BrowserViewController new];`

Comment: @Murlakatam this is a stylistic thing, but `new` is normally less favoured than the more explicit `alloc/init`, but sure it would work and be shorter

Comment: For many years `new` was discouraged but with the advent of ARC Apple documentation now is including the use of `new`.